# How can I obfuscate code from a program made of various DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, obfuscation

Under VS2008, I'm working on a solution containing various DLL project.
Is it possible to obfuscate the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) to merge my assemblies into one, then run that single assembly through the obfuscator of choice. ILMerge has an option to change all types to Internal - I use that flag to increase the obfuscator's effectiveness. ILMerge works just fine on .NET 3.5 executables - I haven't had a chance to test it with the beta bits of .NET 4 yet, however.

All of this can be done transparently by adding a post-build command to your final executable.

The obfuscator I use, by the way, is the free [Babel Obfuscator](http://code.google.com/p/babelobfuscator/).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [DotFuscator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vR81WFXiBA4&feature=player_embedded).

Answer (score 0):

You can obsfucate any available source, but not pre-compiled libraries.

Comment: -1 - this is incorrect. .NET obfuscators operate on compiled libraries and executables - they don't touch the source.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must, you can modify your build process to use [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) or [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to write out the assemblies as source, then obfuscate that as you would normally.